# Convert double for loop to double list comprehension in Python 3?

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, list-comprehension, psycopg2

Given the following structure / logic:

```
for i in range(len(drug_list["drug_list_ids"])):
      for j in range(i + 1, len(drug_list_ids["drug_list_ids"])):
               with pg_get_cursor(pool) as cursor:
                     q = """ SELECT d1.name as drug_1, d2.name as drug_2, description
                             FROM interactions i, drugs d1, drugs d2
                             WHERE d1.id = %s
                             AND d2.id = %s
                             AND i.id1 = d1.id
                             AND i.id2 = d2.id; """
                     cursor.execute(q, (drug_list["drug_list_ids"][i], drug_list["drug_list_ids"][j]))
                     res = cursor.fetchall()

                     if res:
                         for d in res:
                             ddi_list.append(d)
```

I want to convert it to double list comprehension, pass it to my

```
cursor.execute(q, (drug_list["drug_list_ids"][i], drug_list["drug_list_ids"][j]))
```

And continue with the logic.
Please advise how can I do this?

I have managed to create the first step:

```
[(i,j) for i in range(len(drug_list["drug_list_ids"])) for j in range(i + 1, len(drug_list["drug_list_ids"]))]
```

My dictionary: `{'drug_list': ['dabigatran etexilate', 'dasatinib', 'lepirudin', 'atosiban', 'glycocholic acid'], 'drug_list_ids': [2, 3, 1548, 3579, 8]}`

Just to make it clear - the goal is to make unique tuples of drug ids `(2,3)`, `(2,1548)`, ..., `(3, 1548)`, ..., and not `(3,2)`, `(1548,2)`, etc or similar, and present their interactions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overcomplicating matters here. You don't need to run multiple queries in a loop, just use a *single query*:

```sql
SELECT d1.name as drug_1, d2.name as drug_2, description
FROM interactions i
INNER JOIN drugs d1 ON i.id1 = d1.id
INNER JOIN drugs d2 ON i.id2 = d2.id
WHERE
    d1.id in (... id list, see below ...)
AND d2.id = (... same id list, see below ...)
AND d1.id < d2.id
```

I used `INNER JOIN` syntax here rather than multiple tables in the `FROM` clause to group the join conditions into a dedicated location, so the `WHERE` conditions are easier to reason about.

The above passes in all your `drug_list["drug_list_ids"]` ids to both `in (....)` conditions, but then limit the database to only use valid combinations with the `d1.id < d2.id` clause. This generates a full set of possible (ordered) combinations between `d1.id` and `d2.id` just like your for loop, albeit with strict sorted order (using `(8, 1548)` and `(8, 3579)` rather than `(1548, 8)` and `(3579, 8)`).

Psycopg2 actually [accepts tuples as placeholder values](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#adapt-tuple), and expands them into the correct syntax for `... IN ...` testing; the driver includes the parentheses in that case:

```
query_string = """\
    SELECT d1.name as drug_1, d2.name as drug_2, description
    FROM interactions i
    INNER JOIN drugs d1 ON i.id1 = d1.id
    INNER JOIN drugs d2 ON i.id2 = d2.id
    WHERE
        d1.id in %s
    AND d2.id in %s
    AND d1.id < d2.id
"""
with pg_get_cursor(pool) as cursor:
    cursor.execute(query_string, (
        tuple(drug_list["drug_list_ids"]),
        tuple(drug_list["drug_list_ids"])
    ))
    ddi_list = cursor.fetchall()
```

or you can use the Postgres [`... = ANY(ARRAY[...])` test](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparisons.html#id-1.5.8.28.16) instead of `... IN ...`, and make use of the fact that [psycopg2 interpolates lists as `ARRAY` values](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#adapt-list):

```
query_string = """\
    SELECT d1.name as drug_1, d2.name as drug_2, description
    FROM interactions i
    INNER JOIN drugs d1 ON i.id1 = d1.id
    INNER JOIN drugs d2 ON i.id2 = d2.id
    WHERE
        d1.id = ANY(%s)
    AND d2.id = ANY(%s)
    AND d1.id < d2.id
"""
with pg_get_cursor(pool) as cursor:
    cursor.execute(query_string, (drug_list["drug_list_ids"], drug_list["drug_list_ids"]))
    ddi_list = cursor.fetchall()
```

If this wasn't possible, it is a little bit tricky to turn your loops into a list comprehension. Not because list comprehensions can't handle nested loops (just list them in nested order, left to right), but because you need to use *multiple statements* in the loop body to produce the resulting values. Still, because psycopg2's `cursor.execute()` [always returns `None`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html#cursor.execute), you could use `cursor.execute(...) or cursor` to produce the next iterator to loop over, so you'd have something like:

```
[v ... for ... in outer loops ... for v in (cursor.execute(...) or cursor)]
```

This makes use of the fact that you can loop directly over a cursor to get the rows. There is no need to call `cursor.fetchall()` nor a need to test if there were results for that specific query, anyway.

Your nested `for` loops can be much more compactly be expressed with [`itertools.combinations()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations):

```
from itertools import combinations
query_string = """\
    SELECT d1.name as drug_1, d2.name as drug_2, description
    FROM interactions i
    INNER JOIN drugs d1 ON i.id1 = d1.id
    INNER JOIN drugs d2 ON i.id2 = d2.id
    WHERE d1.id = %s AND d2.id = %s
"""
with pg_get_cursor(pool) as cursor:
    combos = combinations(drug_list["drug_list_ids"], r=2)
    ddi_list = [v for id1, id2 in combos for v in (cursor.execute(query_string, (id1, id2)) or cursor)]
```

However, this is *not at all efficient* (sending loads of separate queries to the database) nor is it all that readable. And not necessary, as shown above.

If you must have *tighter control still* over your id pairings, you'd have to use a nested tuple test; put the `d1.id` and `d2.id` columns into an array, and use an `IN ((v1, v2), (v3, v4), ...)` test with the right-hand side, passed to `cursor.execute()` as a tuple of tuples:

```
from itertools import combinations

query_string = """\
    SELECT d1.name as drug_1, d2.name as drug_2, description
    FROM interactions i
    INNER JOIN drugs d1 ON i.id1 = d1.id
    INNER JOIN drugs d2 ON i.id2 = d2.id
    WHERE
        (d1.id, d2.id) IN %s
"""

# list of [id1, id2] lists
combos = tuple(combinations(drug_list["drug_list_ids"], r=2))
with pg_get_cursor(pool) as cursor:
    cursor.execute(query_string, (combos,))
    ddi_list = cursor.fetchall()
```